# Storing attribute values for use with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of links like so

```
<a class="colorBox" href="#" title="#0676B3"></a>
<a ...
<a ... these are similar links with the title containing the color value
<a ...
```

My goal is to use jQuery to grab the value of the title attribute and plug that into the background with .css().

My latest attempt is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a.colorBox').find().attr('title',function(){
          var color = (this);
          $('a.colorBox').css('background',color);
      });
  });
```

of coarse this does nothing but return an error. I'm sure it's because you cant have a callback in the .attr().  I can select the value easily but how do i store it into a variable?  and how would you make the variable change to the next links title value and use that? with the .each() but how?

I am learning still so any code examples would be great or if there is an API function i am not aware about please let me know

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.colorBox').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', this.title);
    });
});
```

However, `title` is probably not the right place to stick a value like this.  you'd likely be better off using a data attribute for what you're trying to accomplish, eg.

```
<a class="colorBox" href="#" data-bgcolor="#0676B3"></a>
```

and changed the javascript to something like

```
$(function() {
    $('a.colorBox').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.css('background-color', self.attr('data-bgcolor'));
    });
});
```

Comment: **thank you** in learning jQuery i have found that when finding the answer it opens a whole new door in understanding the code and how it works.

Comment: You can also get the `data-bgcolor` attribute by using `$(this).data('bgcolor')`.

Comment: **I like it** thanks for the input. I've learned so much here in 10 min I thought you could only put values or variables in the property values of .css() I never thought of what was ofered as a solution.  Many thanks.  And Thank you Rocket I will be adding the .data('bgcolor')

Comment: Inefficient usage of `$(this)`. I agree it won't make much of a difference in this case, but you better cache the jQuery objects, or you will end up with big overheads.

Comment: @shef true, I was just being lazy

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.colorBox').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css('background-color', $this.attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.colorBox').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('title'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $('a.colorBox').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the data attributes

```
<a class="colorBox" href="#" data-bgcolor="#0676B3"></a>
```

In the js you can use jQuery data method to retrieve the value

```
$(function() {
    $('a.colorBox').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('bgcolor'));
    });
});
```